# update-grub caused computer not to boot?

Tags: grub2, lubuntu, initramfs

(I am a bit of an idiot when it comes to this stuff so pleade be patient with me)

I was trying to install windows on a second SSD in my machine(which continually errored out), and some website recommended that I run update-grub to fix the problem. However, now whenever I boot my computer I get dropped into the grub2 shell.

No problems there, i just run the commands listed in this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/556752. This brings me to an ASH prompt with either the message `No root device specified`, or if I specify root=/dev/sdX I get a message asking me to pass a bootarg to init.

So I booted up a live CD of Grub2Rescue and it just boots to `No operating system detected` :/.

I am a little stuped as to how to fix this, and my computer is effectively useless while its not got any way of running an OS. So I need a bit of a hand.

I'm sure that there is a sinple solution out there but I cannot for the life of me find it.

Thanks in advance!

My original working OS was Lubuntu 20.04

Comment: Because you have two drives, do not run auto fix unless someone has reviewed. Sometimes fix is not best option while with one drive it usually is. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @oldfred Erm... I'm not entirely sure what you are saying? What's autofix? PPA version? Boot-info summary? My live installer outright doesn't boot at all (not for any distro)

Comment: I thought it was system not booting. You need live installer version of 20.04 and use it. I always keep multiple flash drives, although most now are larger & have full install, some data and some ISOs to directly boot with grub2's loopmount for repair or install. You can download Boot-Repair ISO, see link, but overtime the ppa is normally more current version of Boot-Repair so better to add it to your existing live installer using ppa instructions in link posted above.

Comment: @oldfred It is my system not booting, but I cannot install a fresh copy as no bootable USB I insert works - it just gives me a blinking cursor

Comment: You then may need to create new flash drive live installer. Sometimes they get corrupted. What brand/model system.

Comment: @oldfred Its self built - but a Gigabyte mobo(Z170M-D3H) running BIOS ver. F21, It's set to use UEFI mode though I have verified that neither UEFI or legacy mode works. I've created and recreated USBs about a thousand times - it still refuses to work. The USBs are created using UNetBootin on my Mac and the drives are formatted as ExFat from MacOS Disk utility

Comment: I have Z170N-Gaming 5 with UEFI f23f update. Make sure you have latest UEFI. You really should only use UEFI, but some tools to create live installer make either UEFI or BIOS, even though ISO is for both. I boot UEFI:PMAP entry to boot flash drive.

Comment: @oldfred I do strive for UEFI. But I still cannot get anything other than a blinking cursor from Live USB on boot, or a grub shell from my SSD. I have access to my EFI partition and main partition from the grub shell and both seem to be in order

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by disconnecting all USB headers from my motherboard and manually booting using

```
linux (hd0,gpt2)/boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2
initrd (hd0,gpt2)/boot/initrd.img
boot
```

It appears I had some sort of faulty ghost USB connected to the system through a media hub.